# Nesting of tabs within quicktabs

Tags: views, routes

is it possible to create new tabs and place them under quick tabs, i.e, i want to create two new quick tabs and add them under (nesting structure) already existing three quick tabs...How can i achieve this

Comment: quicktabs uses blockes in tabs. use quicktab block in quicktabs

Comment: hi...can you be a little more specific

Comment: @kewal, none of the two answers did work for you?

Comment: What was the real problem ? did you reinstalled quicktabs module ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how nested tabs can be created from QuickTabs admin UI. But I believe you can render the child tabs programmatically. The below is how to render a quicktab.

```
<?php
if(module_exists('quicktabs')) {
    $tabs = quicktabs_build_quicktabs('child_tabs'); // where 'child_tabs' is your quicktabs machine name
    print render($tabs);
}
?>
```

You can add such kind of code snippet into your view/block of a particular parent tab.

Let's say for example, you have a parent tab "Parent Tab 1" which is assigned to a block created from **admin/structure/block/add**. You could add the above code snippet into the block body.

If you enable the "PHP Filter" module, you can embed any PHP code into the block body when you select "PHP Filter" text format.

Then, when you access the "Parent Tab 1", you will see another quicktabs inside which is printed programamtically.

Comment: hi...where should i add the code..in which file

Comment: @kewal, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your request well, I think this is the solution supplied by @monymirza. But in the latest stable version of quicktabs you have the possibility to select quicktabs to be show under a tab.

Checkout this image to see : (**ab** is a quicktab instance that has been created earlier, and **c** is the parent tab that will contain **ab**)

[image: Quicktabs under quicktabs]

Comment: hi @jramby ...where can i get to know my already created quick tab instances...

Comment: normally, once you selected **qtabs** in the radio button, Quicktabs instance shows automatically in **Quicktabs instance**... if not, clear your cache.

Comment: yes..i already have tried that...not working...

Comment: Is your qtab instace listed on the page: `admin/structure/quicktabs` ?

Comment: yes it is...m really not getting why the instance is not showing

Comment: This is working for me. Upvoted :)

Comment: yes i know it should work...have no idea why it isn't...thanks anyways..i guess i will install the module again and try...thanks

Comment: this screenshot was taken from a very fresh download of quicktabs module, and i enabled these two modules :
`Quicktabs (quicktabs) 7.x-3.4` and
`Quicktabs Styles (quicktabs_tabstyles) 7.x-3.4`